# Mit App Inventor2

Tags: php, app-inventor

Whats the best (Correct) way of posting data to a server.

I have a app on the go that posts a couple of values of a text field to a apache server.

if i GET via the url http://example.com?fct=1 the $_GET global is populated, but when i HTTP_POST the data is not availiable for the $_POST global, the only way i can access HTTP_POST values is via the php//input stream and this seems wrong to me.

I am thinking this is the way i am building the POST data, i am calling

```
                 Call Web1.PostText>make a list>
                                    make a list>field name
                                               >value

                                    make a list>field name
                                               >value
```

I think the question i am asking is, what is the server expecting to see when i make a HTTP_POST

Comment: probably this example https://puravidaapps.com/export.php can help...

Comment: Have tried that format and still the same, its only availiable on the php//input stream. I know this is a problem in app-inventor as i have set up a local apache server so i can double check things and its the same on the local machine as it is on the server

Comment: What happens, if you use my App Inventor example together with my php script on your server?

Comment: I have just tried your php script and example, and its the same $_POST is not being populated. Same on the local apache server as well. Also the "Bad request" is coming from the first "if" statement

Comment: which means, it's a problem on your php server... as a test you could try 000webhost.com instead...

Comment: Have set that up on 000webhost and its exacly the same, no post data only on the input stream

Comment: I just tested my [example](http://puravidaapps.com/export.php) on 000webhost.com and everything works fine as expected...